# Select fields from two tables based on availibility condition

Tags: sql, db2

I want to create a view which will return fields based on condition: if data is available in table 1 retrieve data from table 1, else retrieve from table 2

Use case:

```
select name, age, date
from table 1
where date = x
```

If no data in table 1 is there for date=x, then
Select name, age, date
 from table 2 where date = x

The view should this.

Is there a wal to have (select *) inside a case statem t

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Select name, age, date from table 1 where date = x
Union All
Select name, age, date from table 2 where date = x
Where Not Exists (select 1 from table 1 where date = x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking something like this. Below I have tried a re-runnable query which will fetch data from Table2 if Table1 has no rows.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(NAME VARCHAR(50), AGE INT, DATE1 DATE)

CREATE TABLE TABLE2
(NAME VARCHAR(50), AGE INT, DATE1 DATE)

INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('NAME1', 10, '01-JAN-2017')

CREATE VIEW vw AS
SELECT NAME, AGE, DATE1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATE1 = '01-JAN-2017'--if condition
UNION
SELECT NAME, AGE, DATE1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATE1 = '01-JAN-2017') -- else condition
```

Your View will give you result from Table2 when Table1 is empty

```
 SELECT * FROM vw;
```

Comment: Thats a duplicate of my answer :D. Initially you wrote answer using `IF` condition

Comment: I have seen he's asking for View. So my The IF EXISTS condition will not work inside it. Its duplicate though.. :p

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But you have hardcoded the date inside the view definition. The view dhould work for multiple dates so that it can be used as: select * from vw where date = ?

Comment: Unfortunately, We can't pass parameters to a view. It's better if you use a table valued user-defined function that takes the parameter you want and returns a query result
Or you can do the same thing by creating a stored procedure.